# Is it possible to use a typedef to especify only a few of the types of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose that there is a template class defined like this:

```
template <typename DOMAIN, typename COUNTERDOMAIN>
class funcType { public:
                   COUNTERDOMAIN calculate(DOMAIN x); 
               }
```

Then the code:

```
typedef funcType<float, float> floatFuncType
```

works nice.

But now suppose that I want just specify the first parameter type of the template class.

I have tried:

```
typedef funcType<float, typename COUNTERDOMAIN> RealFuncType;
```

and also

```
typedef funcType<float, typename COUNTERDOMAIN> RealFuncType<COUNTERDOMAIN>;
```

without any sucess. How can I achieve that? Is it possible?

Comment: `typedef`s are effectively legacy as this point. `using` aliases fully replace *and expand on* the functionality of `typedef` to allow alias templates, while also providing a coherent syntax. In general it's better to prefer `using` in most circumstances

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is an [alias template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).  That would look like

```
template <typename COUNTERDOMAIN>
using RealFuncType = funcType<float, COUNTERDOMAIN>;
```

and then you would use it like

```
RealFuncType<float> foo;
RealFuncType<some_other_type> bar;
```